# Partial site SSL using asp.net login control

Tags: asp.net, ssl, authentication

I'm attempting to convert a home-grown login system to the standard asp.net login control included in .net.  I want all communication on the website for a user not logged in to be in clear text, but lock everything in SSL once the user logs in - including the transmission of the username and password.

I had this working before by loading a second page - "loginaction.aspx" - with a https: prefix, then pulling out the username and password by looking for the proper textbox controls in Request.Form.Keys.  Is there a way to do something similar using the .net login controls?  I dont want to have a seperate login page, but rather include this control (within a loginview) on every page on the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not going to be able to do what you're talking about simply, because the postback (which is what the login control uses) is going to be whatever the page's security is (SSL or non-SSL).

Your best bet in this scenario is to use an IFRAME which contains an HTTPS (SSL) page that just contains thelogin control. You might have to redirect to another page after login that lets you jump out of the IFRAME.

Plan B would be to have a separate form on the page (outside your main FORM) which has the ACTION property point to another page where you handle the login. You will have to roll your your own login code to handle the forms authentication.

Comment: Be aware that using either of these techniques is still not safe, as it is susceptible to a man in the middle attack.  For more information, read this.  http://jlorenzen.blogspot.com/2009/11/preventing-insecure-login-pages.html

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish this by adding an OnClientClick event to the login button control and set it to the following javascript function.
`

```
function forceSSLSubmit() 
{

                var strAction = document.forms[0].action.toString();

                if (strAction.toLowerCase().indexOf("http:") == 0) {
                    strAction = "https" + strAction.substring(4);

                    document.forms[0].action = strAction;
                }

        }
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You aren't going to be able to have your site as non-SSL, with a login box on every page, and then submit the username and password via SSL.

The only way to really accomplish this is to use frames of some sort. This way your entire page could be non-SSL, but the login frame would have to be SSL.

The usual ways of doing this is to either lock down the entire site with SSL, don't worry about having the username and password SSL encrypted and go to SSL after they log in, or go the frame route I mentioned above.