# asp.net forms authentication without login page using ssl

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wish to use forms authentication in an asp.net website, but without a specific login page.
Instead, I'd like to let my users login via a DIV section on the upper right corner of the screen. Moreover, I would like that this DIV section will use SSL.

My suggestion to the implemention is:
1. creating a login.aspx page that contains only the div element with a Form tag.
2. on every page in the site (possibly even in one master page), create an IFrame that contains the login.aspx page.
3. if the user performs a login - display "Hi username" in the login.aspx page. Otherwise, display a login credentials textbox.

This suggestion uses a specific login.aspx page, but it is disguised by the IFrame and the Master page. I think this suggestion is creative and I can't think of a reason why it wouldn't work. Before I'll try it, is this the way to go? Can someone suggest another solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Found an answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96164/partial-site-ssl-using-asp-net-login-control ... it resembles my suggestion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a complex solution to a problem that doesn't exist.

All you need to do is use the Login server control, and edit the template to fit whatever you want.  Place this in the Master Page, and hook it up.  For added benefit, you can write some code to detect if the user is logged in, and if so hide the login control and display the users name.

Alternatively, you could put the login control in a user control that would encapsulate this functionality.

Another alternative is to write your own Login control that does this (it's not difficult).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have 2 questions though:
* I would prefer that only the login control will use SSL and not the whole page, is it possible in accordance with your solution?
* in the loginURL attribute of the web.config, what do I write in order to concur with your solution?

Comment: @lionheart - It is not safe to have the login url be ssl if the page it's hosted on is not ssl.  The reason is that if the page the login form is contained on (even if it's in an iframe) is not encrypted then you can't trust the page itself as an attacker could compromise the parent page via a man in the middle attack and provide a false login url.  Further, There is no way for an end users to verify the certificate if your ssl is only within an iframe or even a form action, so the end user will only see an unsecure page.

Comment: @lionheart - Read this for more information http://jlorenzen.blogspot.com/2009/11/preventing-insecure-login-pages.html

Comment: @lionheart - by the way, you're going to have a problem with using an https iframe.  You can't talk to the parent.  So after the user logins, there's not a good way to tell the parent to reload the page, so the parent page will need to reload the cookie in order for it to "know" that it is now authenticated.

Comment: Your explantion is good (and also explains why I asked about it in the first place). So, as I understand it, we'd rather have a login page (which will use SSL) than use a login control inside a page that is not encrypted.
What if someone else (not from my domain) uses an IFrame which points to my login page - according to your explanation - it is a Man in the middle attack, right?

Comment: the article is not very good. Let's say someone else uses my login page inside an IFrame without https. Then my server redirects the user to https (only the IFrame page) - and, voila, we have a secure connection (the IFrame page) in an unencrypted page (the host page)...

Comment: Moreover, I use Polling in all of my pages, so I don't have a problem with not connective to my hosting page.

Comment: @lionheart - No, you don't have to worry about a man in the middle attack with an ssl login page.  Well, it can still happen, but the user has the opportunity to verify the certificate by clicking on the lock icon in the address bar.  When you place an ssl post action on a form, they don't have the ability to verify the certificate.  You're essentially saying to the user "I am who I say I am, and you can verify me"

Comment: @lionheart - Ideally, you would use SSL throughout the site, since the users authentication cookie could be snatched from non-encrypted pages and used to gain access to the account.  But that's not always practical.

Comment: @lionheart - also, another thing about the dedicated login page is that the user can see the url in the titlebar, and because the entire page is encrypted, they can be confident that nothing has been altered that they can't see.

Comment: You made it clear - so I check this answer as the right answer. Notice that if you use SSL troughout the site, it is very bad for performance. Now, add streaming to the SSL and you will get a very slow site... this is why using SSL is only preferable for authentication in some sites...

Comment: @lionheart - Loss of performance is typically over exaggerated.  If you're getting millions of hits that's one thing, but for most sites you won't even be able to detect SSL.  The majority of the performance cost with SSL is with establishing the first connection, after that it's minimal.  Nobody would stream over SSL, that's silly.

Comment: That's exactly my point... The project I am working on performs streaming via several network internal proxies and routers and there might be connectivity issues if we'll use SSL in the page the streaming performs (for example, every conection might be closed right after 1 minute streaming has gone to the client). This is why SSL is not preffered to all sites in my situation. In addtion, there will be performance issues also if the 256-bit encryption (after the first phase of SSL), so we prefer to use SSL only for authentication at this point. Thanks for the explantions.

Comment: @lionheart - I really don't understand your point.  Streaming is different from web pages.  We're talking about web pages here.  Just because you use ssl for the site doesn't mean you have to use ssl when streaming, and it would be silly to do so.  So silly, that I can't understand why you even mention it.  Streaming and serving pages are two very different things.  It's like complaining about using secure locks on your doors and using using your garage door as an excuse for why you shouldn't be locking everything else.

Comment: This is my SSL link for example (this is how I refer to the web service that streams): https://[externalIPAddress]/stream/[refidofvideo]-[refidofstreamer]-[refid]  ... Maybe our IT department is not the best in the field. I know that this link is a bad convention, but it was not my decision... And I already know, before production, that there will some issues with this link. The client-side streamer and the referenced web service were developed by different section in our company, and they built it so that we will use Web Services for streaming.

Comment: ... or maybe I didn't understand you. But it doesn't matter - I think that we should use SSL in web pages only when we are required to. In my case, not every page in the web system requires SSL. Specifically, the link of the video requires SSL and the page doesn't.

Comment: BTW, we decided to go on a seperate login page via SSL :-)